# C++ -- need help figuring out a while loop issue

Tags: c++

So, need some direction on why this loop is loopin' forever. What I want it do is read a new m, which then sets the terms for the for loops. So, it reads m, which then is calculated into an array, and then reads a new m, etc. Currently it reads one m and does the for loops forever.

```
while(inputFile >> m) {
  while (m != 0) { 
    cout << "m=" << m << endl;
    for (i=0; i < (m*m); i++) { 
      cout << "m times m = " << (m*m) << endl;
      for (ROW=0; ROW < m; ROW++) {
        inputFile >> image[ROW][COL];
        cout << "array= " << image[ROW][COL] << endl;
          for (COL=0; COL < m; COL++) {
            inputFile >> image[ROW][COL];
            cout << "array= " << imagee[ROW][COL] << endl;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample of input file:

```
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Comment: The formatting... my eyes...

Comment: `m` is not modified in the `while` loop, it will always have its initial (non-zero) value.  Consider swapping out `while` for `if` and see if that gets you closer to what you want.

Comment: Apologies about the formatting.

Which while loop should be changed?

Answer (score 2):

You'll find that you won't have an infinite loop if you clean up your code a little bit:

```
while(inputFile >> m) {
  while (m != 0) {
    ...
```

can be combined into this:

```
while(inputFile >> m && m != 0) {
```

Now once the `for-loop`s finish, another `m` will be read from the `inputFile`.

Let's examine why it wasn't working before. Let's say `inputFile` extracted 4 and bound it to `m`.

`while(4 != 0)` is always true, so this is the infinite loop. `m` couldn't be read from `inputFile` again after this.

Alternatively you could write

```
while(inputFile >> m) {
      if (m != 0) {
        ...
```

This would guarantee the entire file is processed, skipping values of 0.

**EDIT**

You needed to consume the newline character with `inputFile.get()` after reading `m`.

I have written a small driver to show you how to do this, but I used `std::vector`s instead of arrays - they're a little easier to use.

Here's the [ideone](https://ideone.com/yIT9fK) with two arrays being read.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <vector>

void output_matrix(const std::vector<std::vector<int > > arr, size_t m) {
    std::cout << "Matrix we read in was: " << std::endl;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        for(size_t j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            std::cout << arr[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void read_matrix(std::istream &in) {
    size_t m = 0;
    while(in >> m && m > 0) {
        std::vector<std::vector<int > > arr(m);
        // Swallow the newline after reading in `m`.
        in.get();
        std::string line;
        for(size_t i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
            arr.resize(m);
            /* 
                `std::getline` will swallow newlines in other lines until `m`
                needs to be read again.
            */
            std::getline(std::cin, line);
            std::stringstream ss(line);
            for(size_t j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
                arr[i].resize(m);
                int temp = 0;
                ss >> temp;
                arr[i][j] = temp;
            }
        }
        output_matrix(arr, m);
    }
}

int main() {
    read_matrix(std::cin);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's still infinite looping, even with your combined while condition.

Comment: @brkville42ny It probably has something to do with a non-integral value being read spuriously.

Comment: Not sure if this information helps, but the file read from is just ints.

Comment: It's still infinite looping. Would an end-of-file measure be appropriate? I know those aren't always wise to use.

Comment: As best as I can tell, yes.

Comment: End-of-file measures aren't necessary if your file is sanitized. Are the numbers one per line or space delimited?

Comment: they're matrices. spaces, yes. but organized so the first number above the matrice tells you the amount of rows.

Comment: Add a sample of your input file in an edit. I think you need to consume a new line character.

Comment: Okay, got it up there. You make a good point about the new line character, I hadn't considered that.

Comment: What do you mean by consume?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
while(inputFile >> m) {
  while (m != 0) {
```

You have an outer loop where you read into `m` and you have an inner loop which ends when `m` is 0. The problem is that the outer loop's condition is not checked again until the inner loop is completed. The inner loop will never be completed, since reading into `m`, which happens to be the outer check as well is never reached.

Generally, if you have loop1 and loop2, loop2 being the inner loop of loop1, then loop2 is reached through loop1, but as soon as loop2 is reached, it must be finished before loop1's condition is checked. If loop1 is not completed, then loop2 will be restarted and so on.